# checking offset().top in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm am using this function to check if the element is in viewport.

```
function topInViewport(element) {
    return $(element).offset().top >= $(window).scrollTop() && $(element).offset().top<= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
 }
```

However one of the id that I'm using is named "top" & so when I use topInViewport($(top)),
I get error in console cannot read property top of null. when I use any other id it works correctly. Though I cannot change the name of the id due to some reason. Is there any workaround?

Comment: How are you passing "top" into the function? is it as a string, or prefixed with `#`? Are you passing in the jQuery object itself? It might pay to add an example of how you're calling `topInViewport()`

Comment: Can you expand a little on this. It may be answerable but is not in its current state as it would require some inference. Can you show a small snippet of how you are using topInViewport?

Comment: I'm passing it like this $(top)

Comment: I'm simple putting topInViewport($(top)) in console.log to check if it returns true or false.

Comment: @stry - Have you waited until the DOM is loaded before you attempt to reference the element with `id="top"`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `top` is a javascript reserved name and it should not be used as a variable name. so instead of passing `top` to function use it like `topInViewport($("#top"))`. You can read about javascript reserved names [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp).